# Why in an RDD, map gives NotSerializableException while foreach doesn't?

Tags: scala, serialization, apache-spark, rdd

I understand the basic difference between `map` & `foreach` (lazy and eager), also I understand why this code snippet

```
sc.makeRDD(Seq("a", "b")).map(s => new java.io.ByteArrayInputStream(s.getBytes)).collect
```

should give

> java.io.NotSerializableException: java.io.ByteArrayInputStream

And then I think so should the following code snippet

```
sc.makeRDD(Seq("a", "b")).foreach(s => {
  val is = new java.io.ByteArrayInputStream(s.getBytes)
  println("is = " + is)
})
```

But this code runs fine. Why so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually fundamental difference between `map` and `foreach` is not evaluation strategy. Lets take a look at the signatures (I've omitted implicit part of `map` for brevity):

```
def map[U](f: (T) ⇒ U): RDD[U]
def foreach(f: (T) ⇒ Unit): Unit
```

`map` takes a function from `T` to `U` applies it to each element of the existing `RDD[T]` and returns `RDD[U]`. To allow operations likes shuffling `U` has to be serializable.

`foreach` takes a function from `T` to `Unit` (which is analogous to Java `void`) and by itself returns nothing. Everything happens locally, there is no network traffic involved so there is no need for serialization. Unlike `map`, `foreach` should be used when want to get some kind of side effect, like in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31489985/upload-each-element-of-an-rdd-to-a-different-file-in-s3).

On a side note these two are actually different. Anonymous function you use in `map` is a function:

```
(s: String) => java.io.ByteArrayInputStream
```

and one you use in `foreach` like this:

```
(s: String) => Unit
```

If you use the second function with `map` your code will compile, although result would be far from what you want (`RDD[Unit]`).

Comment: Nice explanation! I understand `foreach` on shuffling is required, but can you please elaborate why can there be shuffling involved in case of `map`? Is it because the size of resulting partition (after map) may be larger that disk size available in that machine?

Comment: Truth be told I am not sure if `map` alone can trigger shuffling, but important part is that downstream operation may: `rdd.map(f).repartition(1)`. If return type of `f` everything fails.

Comment: Just to be clear. You can use not serializable types inside map function. It just cannot be a return type.

Answer (score 0):

`collect` call after map is causing the issue.
Below are results of my testing in spark-shell.

Below passes as no data has to be sent to other nodes.

```
sc.makeRDD(1 to 1000, 1).map(_ => {NullWritable.get}).count
```

Below calls fail, as map output can be sent to other nodes.

```
sc.makeRDD(1 to 1000, 1).map(_ => {NullWritable.get}).first
sc.makeRDD(1 to 1000, 1).map(_ => {NullWritable.get}).collect
```

Repartition forces distribution of data to nodes, which fails.

```
sc.makeRDD(1 to 1000, 1).map(_ => {NullWritable.get}).repartition(2).saveAsTextFile("/tmp/NWRepart")
```

Without repartition below call passes.

```
sc.makeRDD(1 to 1000, 1).map(_ => {NullWritable.get}).saveAsTextFile("/tmp/NW")
```